# Clickable CALayer UIs

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I have a coverflow-like image carousel grabbing photos w/iPhoto scripting bridge. I have the view set to accept first responder and have implemented methods for left and right arrows, but cannot figure out, conceptually, how to approach making the layers clickable. I know that accepting mouse-down events is the containing view's job, but I can't put the pieces together in my head.

The general point is should I even be trying to make CALayers into UI objects like buttons etc? Because they are very flexible in other ways and I love working with them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is what I pieced together. The context is I have a custom view with one sublayer (CATextLayer) that I'm constraining with the built in layout manager. Here is the awakeFromNib in CustomView.m

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {

CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.backgroundColor = [CGColorHolder black];
layer.layoutManager = [CAConstraintLayoutManager layoutManager];
[self setLayer:layer];
[self setWantsLayer:YES];

CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
textLayer.string = @"TextLater";
textLayer.name = @"textLayer";
textLayer.fontSize = 42.0f;
textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
[textLayer addConstraint:[CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMidX relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMidX offset:0.0f]];
[textLayer addConstraint:[CAConstraint constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMaxY relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMaxY offset:-50.0f]];

}
```

Then I over-ride the mouseDown method for the custom view. Using -hitTest, I return the layer that contains the point where the mousedown occurred, and then set some attribute of the layer to show that its been hit.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {   

CALayer *layer = [self.layer hitTest:NSPointToCGPoint([theEvent locationInWindow])];
layer.backgroundColor = [CGColorHolder red];
```

}

Also, you have to make sure the containing window accepts mouseMoved events:

```
[window acceptsMouseMovedEvents];
```

I don't know how far this will take me in terms of a really sophisticated UI. From here, I will probably delegate what to do to the returned layer based on the name returned. But that could get ugly real fast, so even though I answered my own question here, I would really love to get some input from someone who really knows what they are doing! :D Thanks!